# Why does the creation of a vector of BGL graphs gives a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, boost

I have two classes : `Signal` for my graph edges and `Logic` for my graph vertices. The types ivl_net_logic_t and ivl_signal_t come from IcarusVerilog. The classes are declared in header files :

```
class Logic
{
private:
    std::string name;
    ivl_net_logic_t log;

public:
    Logic(ivl_net_logic_t L);
    ~Logic();

    ivl_net_logic_t getLogic() { return log; }
    void setName(std::string &n) { name = n; }
    std::string getName() { return name; }
}

class Signal
{
private:
    ivl_signal_t signal;

public:
    Signal(ivl_signal_t sig);
    /* Signal(); */
    ~Signal();

    ivl_signal_t getSignal();
}
```

In another header file I also included Boost Graph Library headers and I defined my `Graph` structure :

```
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dominator_tree.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/copy.hpp>

typedef typename boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, Logic, Signal> Graph;
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator VertexIterator;
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator EdgeIterator;
```

In a .cc file I wrote a basic function just to check my graph :

```
void printGraph(Graph &g)
{
    std::cout << "num_vertices(g) = " << num_vertices(g) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "num_edges(g) = " << num_edges(g) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Vertices = [ ";
    VertexIterator vi, vend;
    for (boost::tie(vi, vend) = vertices(g); vi != vend; ++vi)
        std::cout << g[*vi].getName() << " ";
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Edges = [" << std::endl;
    EdgeIterator ei, end;
    for (boost::tie(ei, end) = edges(g); ei != end; ++ei)
    {
        Vertex s = source(*ei, g);
        Vertex t = target(*ei, g);
        std::cout << g[s].getName() << " --> " << g[t].getName() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
}
```

Now in my main code, I create my graph `g` and I try to move it in a vector :

```
Graph g;

/**
 * Add vertices in g and for any vertex v in g, g[v] is a Logic object.
 * Add edges in g and for any edge e in g, g[e] is a Signal object.
 */
printGraph(g);

std::vector<Graph> graph_tracks = {g};
```

Doing this, the compiler said there was an error with the edge property at the line where I insert g in the vector, because the class Signal had no constructor that required no argument :

```
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2190:43: error: no matching function for call to ‘Signal::Signal()’
 2190 |       typename Config::edge_property_type p;
      |                                           ^
includes/Signal.hpp:17:2: note: candidate: ‘Signal::Signal(ivl_signal_t)’
   17 |  Signal(ivl_signal_t sig);
      |  ^~~~~~
includes/Signal.hpp:17:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
includes/Signal.hpp:8:7: note: candidate: ‘Signal::Signal(const Signal&)’
    8 | class Signal
      |       ^~~~~~
includes/Signal.hpp:8:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

So I created the constructor which I commented here in the definition of the Signal class. Also I changed

```
std::vector<Graph> graph_tracks = {g};
```

for

```
std::vector<Graph> graph_tracks;
graph_tracks.push_back(g);
```

Now it compiles and it prints the graph but I get a Segmentation fault just when I push g in the vector. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is highly likely memory corruption. The cause is in code not shown.

Here's your code made self-contained, and simplified/modernized in spots. It works fine and runs clean under sanitizers:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01ba38b45a393ed6)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct ivl_net_logic_t {};
struct ivl_signal_t {};

class Logic {
    std::string     name_ = "unnamed";
    ivl_net_logic_t log_;

  public:
    Logic(ivl_net_logic_t L = {}) : log_(std::move(L)) {}

    Logic(Logic const&) = default;
    ~Logic()            = default;

    ivl_net_logic_t const& getLogic() const { return log_; }
    void                   setName(std::string n) { name_ = std::move(n); }
    std::string const&     getName() const { return name_; }

    friend auto nameMap(auto const& g) { return get(&Logic::name_, g); }
};

class Signal {
    ivl_signal_t signal_;

  public:
    Signal(ivl_signal_t sig = {}) : signal_(std::move(sig)) {}
    Signal(Signal const&) = default;
    ~Signal()             = default;

    ivl_signal_t const& getSignal() { return signal_; }
};

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, Logic, Signal>;
using Vertex         = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge           = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;
using VertexIterator = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator;
using EdgeIterator   = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator;

void printGraph(Graph const& g, std::ostream& os = std::cout) {
    os << "num_vertices(g) = " << num_vertices(g) << "\n";
    os << "num_edges(g) = " << num_edges(g) << "\n";

    os << "Vertices = [ ";
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        os << g[v].getName() << " ";
    os << "]\n";

    os << "Edges = [\n";
    for (auto e : boost::make_iterator_range(edges(g))) {
        Vertex s = source(e, g), t = target(e, g);
        os << g[s].getName() << " --> " << g[t].getName() << "\n";
    }
    os << "]" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Graph g(5);
    g[0].setName("foo");
    g[1].setName("bar");
    g[2].setName("baz");
    g[3].setName("qux");
    g[4].setName("quux");

    add_edge(0, 1, g);
    add_edge(1, 4, g);
    add_edge(4, 2, g);
    add_edge(2, 0, g);

    printGraph(g);
    print_graph(g, nameMap(g), std::cout << "\n---\nOr directly using boost:\n");

    {
        std::vector<Graph> graph_tracks{g};
    }
    {
        std::vector<Graph> graph_tracks;
        graph_tracks.push_back(g);
        graph_tracks.push_back(g);

        for (auto& element : graph_tracks)
            printGraph(element, std::cout << "\n---\nVector element: ");
    }

    printGraph(g, std::cout << "\n---\nStill fine: ");
    print_graph(g, nameMap(g), std::cout << "\n---\nAnd using boost:\n");
}
```

Prints the expected output:

```
num_vertices(g) = 5
num_edges(g) = 4
Vertices = [ foo bar baz qux quux ]
Edges = [
foo --> bar
bar --> quux
quux --> baz
baz --> foo
]

---
Or directly using boost:
foo --> bar
bar --> quux
baz --> foo
qux -->
quux --> baz

---
Vector element: num_vertices(g) = 5
num_edges(g) = 4
Vertices = [ foo bar baz qux quux ]
Edges = [
foo --> bar
bar --> quux
quux --> baz
baz --> foo
]

---
Vector element: num_vertices(g) = 5
num_edges(g) = 4
Vertices = [ foo bar baz qux quux ]
Edges = [
foo --> bar
bar --> quux
quux --> baz
baz --> foo
]

---
Still fine: num_vertices(g) = 5
num_edges(g) = 4
Vertices = [ foo bar baz qux quux ]
Edges = [
foo --> bar
bar --> quux
quux --> baz
baz --> foo
]

---
And using boost:
foo --> bar
bar --> quux
baz --> foo
qux -->
quux --> baz
```

### Summary/Notes

Use sanitizers to your advantage! Chances are that if you run your code under ASAN/UBSAN, you will immediately find the cause. Alternatively, reduce your code to eliminate possible causes. As you can see from my answer, at some point the error goes away.

Note that you talk about "moving graphs" where your code shows no moves. If you move things, references may become stale. Check all places where you keep references to objects that may cease to be valid.

Also note that you return many things by value where they could be `const&`, members weren't const-correct, the property classes smell a bit of "Quasi Classes", and so on. I've simplified a lot of that, but I'd probably suggest more like: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c914a1dd015c371